# How to fix the font issue in HTML?

Tags: html

> I have Html (hello.html) like bellow

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            ¿Hola cómo está?
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> It shows out as "¿Hola cómo está?"  when run in browser
>
> Is there any solution to get correct out put without altering the
>   hello.html file?

I hope that, it is in Spanish language but i looking for any other solution like as change the encode type or font in browser or editor.

Comment: What is your expected output and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: My expected out put is Hello how are you?. It is one of my interview test question. I hope it's in  Spanish language. I am expecting is there any other solution by changing encode type in a browser or editor

Comment: Wait, so you're looking to translate Spanish to English?

Comment: FYI translation is not a font issue nor a character encoding issue.  You might want to change the title of the question.  Nevertheless, given that you said it is an _interview_ question, I've added an answer below.  (Interview questions are sometimes silly thinking out of the box things.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the clarification in the comment section to your question....

If you are using Google Chrome, and your computer is set to an English locale, load the page, then right click on the body, and select "Translate to English."

Sounds like an interview trick question, rather than a programming one.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Just noticed the requirement. But some Spanish characters require Unicode and you have to declare that in your html file.

Put this in your head.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: doesn't work, is there any way to  get the solution by changing the font encode type?

Comment: #Pedantic: Spanish characters do not "require Unicode."  You can get the punctuation and the letters with simple ISO 8859-1.  If you want to get ch and ll and rr as single characters then yes, a larger character set is required.  But Unicode is by no means the only choice (though it is the best).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see whats wrong, if you are refering to the font type in the html and the webpage is different is because of your editor, if you really want to change the font you will need to set the font tag around your text or even better define it in the CSS

Answer (score 0):

No.

You cannot do this without altering the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Place this `<meta>` tag in your Head Section
`<meta charset="UTF-8">`